# Installing an openACC compiler

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, compiling, gcc

I'm trying to run a very simple openACC program, but cannot get it to compile properly. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10.

First, I tried installing the pgcc compiler found at http://www.nvidia.com/openacc. After unpacking the .tar file, I ran `install --help`, because I am very unfamiliar with installation on Ubuntu. The help message contains the following:

`This install program copies files (often just compiled) into destination                                                locations you choose.  If you want to download and install a ready-to-use                                               package on a GNU/Linux system, you should instead be using a package manager                                            like yum(1) or apt-get(1).`

If I understand this correctly, I need to install the compiler using the package manager. However, I have no idea which command I should run in order to do this.
When I run the installation regardless, it gets installed in a sub-folder of the folder I am in. I have no idea where I should place these files, and how to access the pgcc compiler elsewhere.

Having had no success with the NVIDIA package, I tried using the GNU gcc compiler with the `-fopenacc` flag: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/OpenACC. However, I get the following error:

`lto-wrapper: fatal error: could not find accel/nvptx-none/mkoffload in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/ (consider using ‘-B’)`

If I understand this correctly, this has to do with offloading not being configured, as indicated here in the "Typical Compiler Usage" section: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/OpenACC/Quick%20Reference%20Guide.
Trying to figure out how to configure this properly leads me to a dead end.

At this point I am getting incredibly frustrated, as I've been trying to get an incredibly simple program to compile for several hours. I'm following a course on parallel computing, and openMP, MPI and Pthreads were all a matter of including a library or installing a package. I have no idea why it is so difficult to get a working openACC compiler...

Comment: What do you mean by "running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10". Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux, or is it in a virtual machine. Do you have any graphics card?

Comment: If you are using WSL and have NVIDIA graphics card, you may need to install its drivers from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl/download

Comment: If you are using virtual machine then it very unlikely to work. You may have to do full installation of Ubuntu.